# How to remove gap between cells in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` which is having custom cells.Now to main the height width ratio of cell on each device i have added the below code.But for ipad i have defined the fix height/width but in this case it is taking the gap between cells.Please tell me how can i remove the gap between cells?

```
// 1
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    float first_width_per,first_height_per,final_width,final_height;

    first_width_per=((150/self.collectionView.frame.size.width)*100);
    first_height_per=((180/self.collectionView.frame.size.height)*100);
    first_width_per=46.875000;
    first_height_per=48.780487;
    final_width=((first_width_per*self.collectionView.frame.size.width)/100);
    final_height=((first_height_per*self.collectionView.frame.size.height)/100);
    if(IS_IPAD)
    {
        final_width=200;
        final_height=220;
    }
    return CGSizeMake(final_width, final_height);
}
// 3
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5
    ;

}
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section

{
    return 5;

}
```

[image]

Comment: set the width or content inset of your collection view; or define a custom layout for your collection view.

Comment: How can i define such property?

Comment: Please explain how can i make it work?

Comment: i don't known what you say so please add full screenshot

Comment: You need to enlarge the width of cell or also you can set right and left Insets of cell.

Comment: @TechGuy, there is a lots of tutorials about making a custom layout for collection view online; I would start with that documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html

Comment: I have gone through some of the tutorials that i why i have added the **FlowLayout** code here.I have using twi delegate method to define the size of the each cell & also the margins for that.